# Wrong CSS file contents using React

Tags: php, css, laravel

Here's my problem:
I'm using the following CSS file in laravel.blade script:

```
    body {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 8px 14px;
}

#login-panel {
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

And here's the way I'm adding it into my blade file:

```
<head>
<link href="{{ asset('css/general_padding.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

However, it's not working, and when I go to inspector to check my CSS file contents, I see this:
[image]

Which obviously is not my CSS's content.

Comment: It really seems that you modify a different file than what you wanted. You do not even have a `link` tag.

Comment: @LajosArpad pretty sure that I'm modifying the correct file

Comment: Do you have any kind of server-side caching?

Comment: Try to open direct link to css file. Maybe it in resources folder and you not move him in public folder with mix?

Comment: So the CSS file contains a HTML 404 page. This would mean the asset URL in the `<link href="">` is incorrect. Check which URL is generated and whether the CSS file actually exists in the path that URL points to.